# Flying Traveler Airline Company

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list, stack

I am having a little bit problem with the algorithm of this problem.

Problem Statement:

The Flying Traveller Airline Company (FTAir) wants a program to process customer requests to fly from some origin city to some destination city. For each customer, indicate whether a sequence of FTAir flights from the origin city to the destination city exists and produce the itinerary – sequence of flights. Input: Three input text files that specify all the flights information as follow:
• The names of cities that FTAir serves (at least 15 cities).
• Pairs of city names; each pair represents the origin and destination of one of FTAir’s flights.
• Pair of city names; each pair represents a request to fly from some origin city to some destination (at least 5 requests with different scenarios). Each request considered a one-way flight.

Rules:

Find a path from origin city to destination city, if exists.Maintain information about the order in which it visits the cities.Do not visit a city more than once.If there are multiple paths, you may list them all and find least visited cities. (optional). Also, approach via Stack ( using linked list) and Recursion !

My approach is :

First of all we need a data structure to contain all the input text files. Let's say we have the name of the cities in an array, pair of cities (origin --> destination) in a 2D array and the reuqest also in a 2D array.

For a path in the request matrix to exits, it has to be served by our FTAir, so for every request we need to search the origin and destination in the array of cities and if both are a match then only we proceed to our next step.

After finding a match, we have to map the request origin to the flight origins i.e. we have to check whether or not there is any flight from the origin required, if not then again there is no possible path for the travel request.

But if there is a match, we put that origin on to a stack and check it's destination and compare it with the destination requested, if that is a match we have got a direct flight and if that isn't put it on to the stack and look for the destination as an origin in the flight's 2D array. Continue to go on with the procedure, until there is a match. But what if we visit a city twice? Keep a check on the data you enter in the stack, if duplication data found, abort !

I am not able to convert my thoughts into code, can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can't we use graph data structure here, with graph and applying DFS we could easily find if there exists a path from origin to destination and DFS makes use of recursion, let me know if we could use graphs

Comment: Yes, we can use any method which implements recursion or stack(using linked list) !

Answer (score 0):

So let's look at this problem by taking an example.

We have the following list of cities where the Airlines go

```
1. Cambridge (A)
2. Harvard   (B)
3. Hampshire (C)
4. Toronto   (D)
5. Montreal  (E)
6. Quebec    (F)
```

Now we have a mapping pairs of cities between which flight goes to and from.

```
1. (A,B)
2. (C,D)
3. (D,E)
4. (B,C)
```

So now if draw this on a paper our map with 5 cities looks like this

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

So now if you ask me if I want to travel from A to C, is there a path for it, you can simply start a DFS(A) and if you reach C, then answer is yes.

Suppose I ask is there a route from A to F, then applying DFS(A) would give me false and my answer is no.

Now to check whether you have already visited a city or not, just keep a gloval array as visited[] and as you go along DFS method, keep on marking the cities as visited.

Hope this clears your some doubts. Ask more questions in the below comment section.